# Determine If VM is on Azure cloud or on premise from log analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, kql

I need some help to understand if we can anyway pull a value through Azure log analytics if a VM is in on premise or on Azure Cloud ?

Right now i am querying IP ranges from the Heartbeat table in the log analytics and determining if it is on prem or Azure. But this approach does not work for me always as there are new IP ranges and if the VM's are on Express route Vnet. Is there a direct table data which can be pulled from Log Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer it was right there in the Heartbeat table in Log Analytics. Below is the Kusto query.

```
Heartbeat
| distinct Computer , ResourceProvider
| extend VMType = iff(ResourceProvider == 'Microsoft.Compute','AzureVM' , 'OnPremise' )
| project Computer , VMType
```

Answer (score 0):

All Azure VMs will also emit resource Ids and it will be present in "*Heartbeat*" table and "*_ResourceId*" column. Below query should group Azure and Non-Azure VMs.

```
Heartbeat
| distinct Computer, _ResourceId
| extend Environment = iff(_ResourceId != "", "Azure", "Non-Azure")
```